# Posts about ATG - feels like a scam

Tags: discussion

A user has posted a bunch of answers about "ATG" this, that and the other. Never heard of them , and nor has google.

There appears to be a set of spammy posts on Flickr about "ATG" like this

https://www.flickr.com/groups/2497488@N21/discuss/72157639746143256/

and, particularly this, all originating from one user.

https://www.flickr.com/groups/canoneos5dmarkii/discuss/72157625911050907/

No idea what's going on but frankly, it smells....

Comment: I don't have anything concrete at this point.

Comment: Closing this for now. I don't generally want to discuss issues about users directly in Meta like this.

Comment: JoanneC: understood. Wasn't sure how else to raise it. I've removed specific user details from the question, but obviously history may still show them.